# How can I write back to same file I read from using a wildcard path?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using the following PowerShell script to remove quotation marks in a .CSV file:

```
(gc C:\TestQualifier*.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file C:\TestQualifier.csv -Fo -En ascii
```

The file will always be named TestQualifier but may have a date and time stamped on the end of the filename (e.g. TestQualifier10082017091010). The wildcard handles this at the source, but I can't figure out how to write the source filename to the output filename. `Out-File` does not accept wildcards.

Ideally I would also like to overwrite the existing file when the file is output.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the path and, ideally, save it in a variable to use it down the pipe.

```
$path = Resolve-Path C:\TestQualifier*.csv | Select -Expand Path
```

`Resolve-Path` on its own returns `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` objects so we expand the path property to get just that.

So assuming there is only one path that will match that filter it is now stored, as a string, in `$path`.

```
(Get-Content $path) | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $path -Force -Encoding ascii
```

If this is one-off code, it does not matter, but if you plan on using that later, it might be easier for you to avoid using aliases and to use full parameter names.
Using full command and parameter names makes the code easier to read both now and later.

Comment: Good advice re full names; a simpler alternative to `Resolve-Path C:\TestQualifier*.csv | Select -ExpandProperty Path` that expands to full provider-native paths (which are safe to use even in .NET method calls) is: `Convert-Path C:\TestQualifier*.csv`. (The latter is the equivalent of `Resolve-Path C:\TestQualifier*.csv | Select -ExpandProperty ProviderPath`.)

Answer (score 2):

To offer another solution, which uses the `-pv` (`-PipelineVariable`) common parameter (PSv4+):

```
Get-Item C:\TestQualifier*.csv -pv file | % {
  (Get-Content $file.FullName) | % { $_ -replace '"' } |
    Out-File $file.FullName -Force -Encoding Ascii
}
```

<sup>* As in the question, the `Get-Content` call is enclosed in `(...)` to ensure that the entire input file is read *up front*, which enables writing the results back to the input file.

* `.FullName` is not strictly needed in this case, but it's safer to use it, because a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance doesn't *always* string-convert to the file's *full* path - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3772).

* `$_ -replace '"', ""` was shortened to `$_ -replace '"'`, given that *not* specifying a replacement string is the same as specifying the empty string.</sup>

Note the use of `Get-Item` in a first step in order to retrieve the files of interest, and how `-pv file` defines variable `$file`, which then represents the input file at hand inside the `%` (`ForEach-Object`) script block.
More generally speaking, `$file` contains the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance output by `Get-Item` in each pipeline-processing step, allowing script blocks in subsequent pipeline commands to reference it.

Comment: I always had trouble getti ga good use case out of pv. Nice to see ot i  play

Answer (score 0):

If more than one file has to be processed with the wildcard:

```
ForEach ($File in (gci C:\TestQualifier*.csv)){(gc $File)|%{$_ -replace '"'}|out-file $File -Fo -En ascii}
```

Verbose

```
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem C:\TestQualifier*.csv)){
    (Get-Content $File) | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '"'
    } | Out-File $File -Force -Encoding ascii
}
```